`\PrintIndex` does not work in `l3doc` class
I'm writing a manual for my class and I'd like to create an index at last. However, it seems not work. It returns errors like Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup., Misplaced alignment tab character &., and \verb ended by end of line., etc. The following is my MWE:
\documentclass{l3doc}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\cs{fooa}, \cs{foob}, \cmd{\fooc}, ...

\PrintIndex

\end{document}

And I found that content in the .ind file appears so strangely
\begin{theindex}

  \item font 
    \subitem \verb*&
      \subsubitem \fooa&}, \hdpindex{usage}{MMMMI-1}
  \item font 
    \subitem \verb*&
      \subsubitem \foob&}, \hdpindex{usage}{MMMMI-1}
  \item font 
    \subitem \verb*&
      \subsubitem \fooc&}, \hdpindex{usage}{MMMMI-1}

\end{theindex}



you must call makeindex with a special style file makeindex -s gind.ist ...
